# How to convert a generic type T into an empty collection if it is as a collection

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I want a similar operator to default(T) but returning an empty collection if T is a collection type instead of null. How would you do that in PCL library?

Example:

```
Where T are following types
T -> string
T1 -> IEnumerable<string>
T2 -> IList<string>

default value would be returned as following:
Default<T> -> null
Default<T1> -> IEnumerable<string> (empty)
Default<T2> -> IList<string> (empty)
```

Comment: Does `T` extend `IEnumerable`, or do you need a new `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: No T doesn't extent IEnumerable. It might be of any type.

Comment: Then how do you define "collection type"?

Answer (score 2):

The method that you're looking for is the static `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`. I'm just not sure what you mean by "collection type".

```
var defaultAny             = default(T);
var defaultCollectionOfAny = Enumerable.Empty<T>();
```

**edit**

Following up on your updated question: what concrete type should be used for any given interface? For `IList<string>`, you'll probably want a simple `List<string>`. But this isn't always so obvious.

Consider this fictional method call:

```
var collection = Default(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>)
```

Possible return types:

- `Dictionary<string, string>`
- `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`
- `KeyValuePair<string, string>[]`
- ...